# Cannot use worker_threads in electron main thread

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge, node-worker-threads

In Electron v21.3.0 and electron-forge, when i try to run a node worker thread in the main process, i cannot require anything from the module 'worler_threads'

```
// myWorker.js
const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads');
```

parentPort is not defiend.

This happens only if i make the setup using forge maker: "Windows Squirrel."